# get values form NSMutableArray from end to start

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, reverse

I want to take the values from NSMutableArray but want to read from last index to 1st index

thank you

Comment: Have you tried `for ( int i = [array count]-1; i>=0; i--)` ?

Comment: Otherwise, try one of these: `– sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:`
`– sortedArrayUsingSelector:`
`– sortedArrayUsingComparator:`

Answer (score 5):

```
for (id someObject in [someArray reverseObjectEnumerator])
{
    //do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2 other options:

Simple for-loop (surely not recommended):

```
for (int i = [array count]-1; i >= 0; ++i)
    id value = [array objectAtIndex: i];
```

Block-based enumeration:

```
[array enumerateObjectsWithOptions: NSEnumerationReverse
                        usingBlock: ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
                              //do something
                        }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer is useful, but this form may be useful when you want to mutate the array:

```
while ([arr count]) {
  id obj  = [arr lastObject];
  // use obj
  [arr removeLastObject];
}
```